# T-SQL FIxed-Width Output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a way to get SQL Server to output a string with a fixed width? For example

```
SELECT FixedWidth(cola, 7), FixedWidth(colb, 10) ...
```

That would output 2 strings with 7 and 10 characters wide repsectively? Something like

```
'test   ' 'foobar    '
'aabbb  ' 'hello     '
'foo    ' 'bar       '
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  SELECT 
       CAST(cola as char(7)) as cola, 
       CAST(colb as char(10)) as colb ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast to fixed char or nchar. For example

```
SELECT CAST(column1 as nchar(10)) [...]
```